# how to make product list in homepage and sub page look the same?

Tags: magento-1.9

so our products look really nice on our category page:
http://www.avfdevelopments.org/ecommerce/index.php/sub.html

but look ghastly on the homepage - how can i get them to look the same?

http://www.avfdevelopments.org/ecommerce/index.php/

Al the product i want on our homepage are latest products from ALL categories.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the homepage to a category page.

System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages

Change from 'cms' to catalog/category/view/id/category_id

Where you find the category id by opening the category in admin and seeing what the ID is.

Comment: Hi Wolfie, thanks for your response so the new path would be: catalog/category/view/id/3 - if category 3 is the category i want to use?

Comment: ahh fantastic - how do i do it so that more than 1 category appears?

Comment: my mistake - didn't realise you wanted more on there than what you have in the category pages. Nonetheless I hope you have learned of one approach.

Comment: i just want more than 1 category :)